# Google Speech API Streaming Node.js 'Invalid 'audio_content' error

Tags: node.js, windows, audio-streaming, google-speech-api, google-cloud-sdk

I'm very new to programming.

I was running Google SDK on Windows 10. Downloaded and installed prerequisites to run https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/recognize.js

I was previously having an issue with sox, but got that fixed thanks to another thread. Currently this is what happens when I ask recognize.js to listen -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\nodejs-docs-samples\speech>node recognize.js listen
Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.
{ Error: Invalid 'audio_content': contains no audio data.
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\nodejs-docs-samples\speech\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:270:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\nodejs-docs-samples\speech\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:236:8)
at readCallback (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\nodejs-docs-samples\speech\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:311:12)
code: 3,
metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: { 'content-disposition': [Object] } } }
```